# Postgres: Acquire lock on target records before updating

Tags: postgresql, deadlock

I'm working with a PostgreSQL statement. My goal is to modify the statement to avoid the deadlock problem. Currently, there are 2 statements updating the same records. This must happen in some times and cannot be avoided because it's the real operation in the production.

What I want to do is to create the `UPDATE` statement that will obtain lock to all records that will be updated. I have tried `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, `LOCK TABLE as exclusive mode` , `UPDATE` in a `LOOP`". Neither has worked for me. The deadlock still happened. You guys who have any ideas for this?

Comment: You'll need to provide an example. I assume you're updating related rows in multiple tables?

Comment: Please show sample code and a timeline that produces the deadlock. See this answer I wrote recently for an example of what I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455962/calculate-next-primary-key-of-specific-format/12456645#12456645

Comment: The key things with deadlock avoidance is that you need to acquire your locks in the same order from each transaction. Annoyingly `UPDATE` doesn't have `ORDER BY`, so `SELECT ... ORDER BY ... FOR UPDATE` is often needed.

Answer (score 1):

Mind using [advisory locking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS), in case you cannot figure out the exact relations or records to lock.